# A maximization program expressed by per capita variales - Ramsey model

Tags: economic-growth, environmental-economics

I have a problem to be maximized with the following program

$$max\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\{ u\left(C\right)+\beta S^{\chi}\right\} e^{-\rho t}dt$$
s.t

$$\dot{K}=AK-C$$
$$\dot{S}=\left(1-S\right)S-\gamma AK$$

where $K$ is physical capital $S$ is the natural capital. All capital letters represent aggregate variables. The economy enjoys the natural capital as a positive amenity and the natural capital is negatively affected by the physical capital accumulation by a rate of $\gamma$.

I am trying to express this program by ***variables per capita*** since I would like to have constant steady state values. Note that the population grows at rate $n$. ($L(t)=L(0)e^{nt}$ with $L(0)=1$) It is easy for physical capital.

I will have something as

$$\dot{k}=Ak-nk-c$$

However, for the natural capital, the logistic growth of the natural capital and the amenity $S^{\chi}$ complicate the issue.

Is there a way to express all the maximization program by variables per capita? I would really appreciate if you have some hints to give or some solutions. Or if it is not possible to express by per capita variables, I would be happy to know the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take the differential equation for the natural resource. I will write $S \equiv sL$ where lowercase is the per capita magnitude. So

$$\dot{S}=\left(1-S\right)S-\gamma AK$$

$$\implies \frac {d(sL)}{dt} = (1-sL)sL - \gamma AkL$$

$$\implies \dot sL + s\dot L = sL - s^2L^2 -\gamma AkL$$

Divide by $L$ to get

$$ \dot s + sn = s - s^2L -\gamma Ak$$

and using $L=e^{nt}$ and re-arranging we get

$$ \dot s = (1-n) s - s^2e^{nt} -\gamma Ak$$

Setting this equal to zero, we have a quadratic polynomial in $s$

$$\dot s = 0 \implies e^{nt}s^2 - (1-n) s + \gamma Ak=0$$

We see that the leading term increases as $t$ increases. The only way to maintain equality with zero, and constant $s$, is if $k$ decreases as time passes (and this will be only temporary since $k$ cannot turn negative).

So it appears that you cannot have a "steady state in per capita terms" for all variables here, consumption, capital *and* the natural resource.
Most probably you can maintain consumption and capital at constant steady state values while the *per capita*, at least, natural resource depletes to extinction (but you have to show that this is optimal with respect to intertemporal utility maximization).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that population size (N) is 1 and grows at the rate n=0, then would it not solve the problem? Defining, $s = S/N, k = K/N$

$\dot{S} = S -S^2 -\gamma AK    
\implies \frac{\dot{s}}{s} = 1 - sN - \gamma A\frac{k}{s}  
\implies  \frac{\dot{s}}{s} = 1 - s - \gamma A\frac{k}{s} $

Likewise for the utility function I think.

Comment: Thanks for this. If the population size is 1 how can it grow at rate $n$? The size will change, no?

Comment: Yes. What I mean is that if we assume that N(t)=1, then even if population is growing (beyond 1), N(t) will disappear from your equation of motion. I admit my method is a bit crude.

Comment: I do not understand. N(t) is not a constant, it evolves over time. If it goes beyond one, how can it disappear?

Comment: By the way, you can have n = 0. In that case, level variables are already per capita with N(t)=1

Comment: If there is no population growth, I agree but in the case where n is not zero, I do not understand your method.

Comment: Yes I see your point now. Will edit my answer.